# How can I limit WordPress category selection to just one?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type and a custom taxonomy setup - pretty standard stuff.

However, I would like to know how I can restrict my client from selecting more than one taxonomy category per post?

I don't mind them being able to create and delete taxonomy types, but I don't want them selecting more than one. Because these are checkboxes, they CAN. Perhaps radio buttons might work?

I have seen solutions use jQuery to change these fields, but they seem a bit hacky. What's the best practice way to do this?

Attached, is a screenshot of my custom taxonomy box.

[image: Custom taxonomy]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671566/1287812) another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't a full blown answer but something as simple as listing the categories (or taxonomy terms) with a dropdown would do the trick. I don't know of one personally but there's got to be plugin that does this. No offense but this certainly strikes me as a problem that's been solved before.

Comment: Well that's what I thought, but I only find hackey answers from 3 years ago...and even they aren't ideal. Was trying to locate an idea that was perhaps standard via native WP options.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we have to use jQuery. It's "hacky" but works easily and a pure PHP/WP solution is really complex if my memory serves me well.
This is the necessary code:

```
jQuery("#categorychecklist input").each(function(){
    this.type = 'radio';
});
```

We have to run the code on the pages `/wp-admin/post.php` and `/wp-admin/post-new.php`. It should run on load and then run again if a new category is created. To solve the new category issue I used a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'post-new' ) as $hook )
    add_action( "admin_footer-$hook.php", 'convert_cats_to_radio' );

function convert_cats_to_radio(){
    global $post;
    if( $post->post_type !== 'post') // select your desired Post Type
        return;

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function makeRadioButtons(){
        jQuery("#categorychecklist input").each(function(){
            this.type = 'radio';
        });
    }
    function newCategoryObserver(){
        // Example from developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
        var targetNode = document.getElementById('categorychecklist');
        var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
        var callback = function(mutationsList) {
            for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
                    makeRadioButtons();
                }
            }
        };
        var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    }
    newCategoryObserver();
    makeRadioButtons();
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

**Relevant**: [this old plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-checklist-tree/) still works perfectly to solve the issue of sub-categories hierarchy. By default in WP, when one sub-category is selected it doesn't show under its parent category but on top of the list. It's also a jQuery solution and written by a lead WP core developer at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in case you need the checkboxes to act like radio buttons, but still be able to uncheck them all:

```
(function() {
    // Allow only one selection
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="tax_input[event-series][]"][type="checkbox"]');
    checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            checkboxes.forEach((el) => {
                if (item !== el) {
                    el.checked = false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

It's looping through each checkbox and it's adding a click event listener. If you click on a checkbox, it's going to remove the check state on each of the elements, but itself.
However, it's still keeping the ability to uncheck an option if it's already selected.

I've added the scripts only in the administration. To do so, you can use the [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).

Hope this one helps somebody! :)